# Extract 2 Integers from String

Tags: java, string, split, integer, substring

```
String weapon = "pistol . <1/10>";
Result:
int clip = 1;
int ammo = 1;
```

format of the string = (WEAPON) . <(CLIP)/(AMMO)>
And I need the Clip and Ammo values.

So how I can extract those two values of the String.
I can split it by "/" by it will still face: "gun <1" and "10>"
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the non-digits characters like this:

```
String s = "pistol . <1/10>";
String[] numbers = s.replaceAll("^\\D+","").split("\\D+");
```

Now `numbers[0]` is `1` and `numbers[1]` is `10`.

- `s.replaceAll("^\\D+","")` removes the non digit characters at the beginning of the string, so the new string is now `"1/10>"`
- `.split("\\D+")` splits on non digit characters (in this case `/` and `>`) and ignores the trailing empty strings if any

---

Alternatively, if the format is always exactly as you mentioned in your question, you could look for that specific pattern:

```
private final static Pattern CLIP_AMMO = Pattern.compile(".*<(\\d+)/(\\d+)>.*");

String s = "pistol . <1/10>";
Matcher m = CLIP_AMMO.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    String clip = m.group(1); //1
    String ammo = m.group(2); //10
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there possibility to get the weapon name as well? (So I got 2 Integers and 1 String)

Comment: @user1621988 with the second approach, something like: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)\\b.*<(\\d+)/(\\d+)>.*");` would work. The weapon will be `m.group(1)`, clip will be `m.group(2)` and ammo `m.group(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String weapon = "pistol . <1/10>";

String str = weapon.substring(weapon.indexOf("<")+1,weapon.indexOf(">")); // str = "<1/10>"

int clip = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0,str.indexOf("/"))); // clip = 1

int ammo = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("/")+1)); // ammo = 10
```

clip = 1

ammo = 10

Done..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too...

**Extracting the the values WEAPON, CLIP and AMMO from the String "(WEAPON) . <(CLIP)/(AMMO)>"**

```
String str = "(WEAPON) . <(CLIP)/(AMMO)>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Extracting the the values 1, 10 from the String "pistol . <1/10>":**

```
List<String[]> numbers = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String str = "pistol . <1/10>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\<(.*?)\\>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()) {
   numbers.add(matcher.group(1).split("/"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String weapon = "pistol . <1/10>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(weapon); 
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (m.find()) {
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
}
System.out.println("CLIP: " + numbers.get(0));
System.out.println("AMMO: " + numbers.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

And then u split the resultant substrings by "<" (gun <1) and ">" (10>)respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String weapon = "pistol . <1/10>";
    String test = "";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<.*?>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(weapon);

    if (matcher.find())
        test = matcher.group(0);

    test = test.replace("<", "").replace(">", "");
    String[] result = test.split("/");

    int clip = Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
    int ammo = Integer.parseInt(result[1]);
    System.out.println("Clip value is -->" + clip + "\n"
            + "Ammo value is -->" + ammo);
}
```

Output:

```
Clip value is -->1
Ammo value is -->10
```